# How get the parent object inside a child object

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm making a MMORPG game involving several data classes such as `Level`, `Attack`, `Skill`, `Constitution` so there is a lot of nested objects.
For exemple I have a `Game` object which contains a `Player` object(containing a `Position` object) and a `Dungeon` object. I don't find a way to access `game.dungeon` inside `game.player` :

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, player, dungeon):
        self.player = player
        self.dungeon = dungeon

class Player:
    def __init__(self, position, level):
        self.position = position
        self.level = level
    
    def move(self, direction):
        pass
        #some tests to see if the player can move in this direction

class Position:
    def __init__(self, rooms):
        self.rooms = rooms

class Dungeon:
    def __init__(self, height, width, floor):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.floor = floor

class Room
    def __init__(self, doors)
        self.doors = doors

game = Game(Player(Position(0, 0, 0), 1), Dungeon(np.array("contains some Room objects")))
```

Here within the `Player.move` method in the `Player` class I want access `game.dungeon` to do some tests. I know I just have to put dungeon as a player attribute but I want to have a logical a hierarchy because I have a bunch of classes not shown here.

Comment: When you call `Game(Dongeon(Room(Item(...))))`, you're mandating that the `Item` be created before the `Room`, the `Room` be created before the `Dongeon`, and the `Dongeon` be created before the `Game`. If you want to go that route, then it means that all of those objects need to at least temporarily/transiently work without their "parents". I'm not sure that's a good design choice.

Comment: Consider instead having a `game.createDongeon(*args, **args)` call _on the `Game` object_, which can do something like `self.dongeons.append(Dongeon(game=self, *args, **args))`; likewise for the other objects that can have children.

Comment: (...by the way, do you mean "dungeon", or is the different spelling intentional?)

Comment: That said -- I'm not sure this is a great Stack Overflow question; it's more asking about good design practices, which is more the domain of our sister site [programmers.se]; here, we're focused on narrow, specific implementation problems, and try to steer clear of anything that calls for opinions.

Comment: Like I said I have a lot of data classes separated in a total of 9 files, to make my problem easier to understand I wrote this program just to show you what I want to do because I have the same issue with some objects in player. So my question is: Is there a way to access game from player ?

Comment: Likewise @CharlesDuffy programming questions related to game design are also on-topic at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com -- might be an even better fit than Software Engineering as the folks there are contextual subject-matter experts.